# Extract value from link in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, match, href

I have a function in Powershell that gets the content of a file and breaks it up into fields to put into a CSV file. I'm wondering if there's a way to get a value from the link and add it to the columns that are sent to the CSV file while keeping the link column intact.

```
function Convert2CSV {
(Get-Content $input_path) -match "href" | % {
$data = ($_ -replace '(?:.*)href="(.*?)">Date:\s*([\w\.]+)\s*([\w\:]+)\s*Item:\s*(.*)</a>(?:.*)' , '$1;$2;$3;$4').Split(";")
New-Object psobject -Property @{
    "Link" = $data[0]
    "Date" = $data[1]
    "Time" = $data[2]
    "Item" = $data[3]
    }
} #| Export-Csv $output_file -NoTypeInformation
}
```

The value I'm looking for is either

```
FeedDefault_.*?(&) or _Feed.*?(&)
```

Am I correct in thinking that I can add some sort of if statement to the "Link" = $data[0] part?

Sample Output as requested.

```
Value in Link   |   Link                                                                    |   Date        |   Time    |   Item            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
bluepebbles     |   http://www.domain.com/page.html?FeedDefault_bluepebbles&something       |   2013-05-19  |   13:30   | Blue Pebbles      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
redpebbles      |   http://www.domain.com/page.html?Feed_redpebbles&something               |   2013-05-19  |   13:31   | Red Pebbles       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

CSV Formatted

```
Value in Link,Link,Date,Time,Item
"bluepebbles","http://www.domain.com/page.html?FeedDefault_bluepebbles&something","2013-05-19","13:30","Blue Pebbles"
"redpebbles","http://www.domain.com/page.html?Feed_redpebbles&something","2013-05-19","13:31","Red Pebbles"
```

So entering in

```
$input_path = 'f:\mockup\area51\files\link.html'
$output_file = 'f:\mockup\area51\files\db_csv.csv'

$tstampCulture = [Globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo("en-GB")

$ie = New-Object -COM "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Visible = $false

$ie.Navigate("file:///$input_path")

$ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a") | % {
  $_.innerText -match 'Date:\s*([\w\.]+)\s*([\w\:]+)\s*Item:\s*(.*)'
  $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    "Link" = $_.href
    "Date" = $matches[1]
    "Time" = $matches[2]
    "Item" = $matches[3]
  }
  if ( $obj.Link -match '\?Feed(?:Default)?_(.*?)&' ) {
    $obj | Add-Member –Type "NoteProperty" –Name "LinkValue" –Value $matches[1]
  }
  $obj
} #| Export-Csv $output_file -NoTypeInformation
```

Returns an error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:12 char:38
+     $ie.document.getElementsByTagName <<<< ("a") | % {
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementsByTagName:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

So I'm pretty sure that I probably messed something up. :)

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are the two values litteral? Because they consist of regex-wildcards etc, so it's hard to understand what you want. Do you want to see if the url contains exactly `FeedDefault_.*?(&)` or `_Feed.*?(&)` and if match, add them in a column called ex. `Match` ?  Include some sample output what the result should look like

Comment: I want to extract what's between `FeedDefault_ and the &` if it's in the link or what's between `_Feed and the &` if it's in the link. Then add that value to a column that gets spit out to the CSV file while keeping the link column intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd suggest to use `-match` instead of `-replace`. The resulting `$matches` array already contains the submatches you're interested in, so there's no need to manually create this array.

```
Get-Content $input_path | ? { $_.contains("href") } | % {
  $_ -match 'href="(.*?)">Date:\s*([\w\.]+)\s*([\w\:]+)\s*Item:\s*(.*)</a>'
  $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    "Link" = $matches[1]
    "Date" = $matches[2]
    "Time" = $matches[3]
    "Item" = $matches[4]
  }
  $obj
} #| Export-Csv $output_file -NoTypeInformation
```

The additional information can be extracted from `$obj.Link` with a second `-match` and then added to the custom object via `Add-Member`:

```
if ( $obj.Link -match '\?Feed(?:Default)?_(.*?)&' ) {
  $obj | Add-Member –Type "NoteProperty" –Name "LinkValue" –Value $matches[1]
}
```

Also, since your input files are probably HTML files you should consider using the `InternetExplorer` COM object, which will give you far better control over the extracted tags than processing the files line-by-line.

```
$ie = New-Object -COM "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Visible = $false

$ie.Navigate("file:///$input_path")
while ( $ie.Busy ) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

$ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a") | % {
  $_.innerText -match 'Date:\s*([\w\.]+)\s*([\w\:]+)\s*Item:\s*(.*)'
  $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    "Link" = $_.href
    "Date" = $matches[1]
    "Time" = $matches[2]
    "Item" = $matches[3]
  }
  if ( $obj.Link -match '\?Feed(?:Default)?_(.*?)&' ) {
    $obj | Add-Member –Type "NoteProperty" –Name "LinkValue" –Value $matches[1]
  }
  $obj
}
```

Comment: thanks for the wonderful idea! only problem is when I enter in the code, I get the error. `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:12 char:38
+     $ie.document.getElementsByTagName <<<< ("a") | % {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementsByTagName:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull`

Comment: My bad. `Navigate()` returns immediately, but you still have to wait for IE to finish loading the page. I forgot to add a wait-loop when writing my answer, so your test probably tried to access the `document` object before the page was loaded completely. Fixed.

Comment: that would make sense, however I'm still getting the error message even with the new code. I'll play around with things and see if I can't get something working. Thanks again for the pointer in the right direction!!